# -O2 ломает программу

Tags: c++

Есть код, который прекрасно работает без оптимизаций:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

class JavaRandom
{
private:
    int64_t rseed;

    inline constexpr int32_t next(int32_t bits)
    {
        rseed = (rseed * 0x5DEECE66DLL + 0xBLL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFLL;

        return int32_t((rseed) >> (48 - bits));
    }
public:
    inline constexpr int32_t nextInt(int32_t bound)
    {
        int32_t r = next(31);
        int32_t m = bound - 1;
        if ((bound & m) == 0)
            r = int32_t((bound * (int64_t)(r)) >> 31);
        else
            for(int32_t u = r; u - (r = u % bound) + m < 0; u = next(31));

        return r;
    }

    inline constexpr void setSeed(int64_t seedIn)
    {
        rseed = (seedIn ^ 0x5DEECE66DLL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFLL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    JavaRandom rand;
    const int32_t x = 1000;
    const int32_t z = 1000;
    const int64_t seed = 1;
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rand.setSeed(seed + (int64_t)((x+i) * (x+i) * 4987142) + (int64_t)((x+i) * 5947611) + (int64_t)(z * z) * 4392871LL + (int64_t)(z * 389711) ^ 987234911LL);
        cout << rand.nextInt(10) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
1
9
9
7
4
4
2
5
6
1
```

Но как только я включаю любой из уровней оптимизаций, программа выдаёт вот это:

```
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

Что вызывает такие ошибки?

Comment: Похоже на Неопределенное Поведение при переполнении знакового целого. Замените их на беззнаковые.

Comment: вообще это крайне интересно, на сколько я знаю стандартом с++ переполнение знакового целочисленного является UB. Забавно, что об этом я узнал, когда получил исключние от CUDA - долго пытался разобраться в чем проблема, а когда узнал, что проблема с переполением, разрабы прямо сослались на страндарт с++ и предложили использовать беззнаковые целочисленные если возможно переполнение

Comment: Если заменить знаковые целые на беззнаковые, программа работает не корректно. При переводе из int32_t в int64_t(в функции main) в 32-63 биты должен записаться знаковый бит из int32_t, но при использовании беззнаковой арифметики такого не происходит. Как это можно обойти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, при переполнении знакового целого происходят странные вещи, и всё ломается.
Чтобы исправить баг нужно было просто в кое-каких местах заменить знаковую арифметику на беззнаковую.
В классе JavaRandom заменил определение переменной с int64_t rseed на uint64_t rseed,
В функции main() константам x, z переопределил тип с int32_t на uint32_t,
В цикле for в этой длинной строке(где вызывается rand.setSeed) после каждого (int64_t) я добавил (int32_t), и всё заработало.
Теоретически возможно переполнение, когда происходит сложение переменной x и i, но значение x в ходе работы программы не должно превысить 1 185 000(по условию, которое я забыл упомянуть), а значение i не превысит 10, так что не вижу смысла чинить это